# How to store bitcoin value and other currencies values together in MySql database?

Tags: mysql, performance, decimal

I need to store bitcoin value and other currencies values together , I have a decimal column (16,8) for amounts. It behaves normally for bitcoin values , but when I want to store other currencies like Usd or Eur It becomes like this eg. `100 Usd` becomes `100.00000000` .  `0.50 Usd` becomes `0.50000000`

My question is should I store bitcoin values and other curriencies values in same column? 
I will have millions of rows, is it bad for performance (read , write , count ) or this is just cosmetic issue?

Comment: There is also a "correctness" question.  But without knowing how you plan to use the data, we can address any of the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you use a DECIMAL(16, 8) field, values are stored with 6 decimal digits. It doesn't matter if they are bitcoins, euros, dollars, ...

If you want to use a [monetary type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-money.html), then you should take care and properly configure the server just to hold all values.

> **8.2. Monetary Types**
>
> The money type stores a currency amount with a fixed fractional
>   precision; see Table 8.3. The fractional precision is determined by
>   the database's lc_monetary setting. The range shown in the table
>   assumes there are two fractional digits. Input is accepted in a
>   variety of formats, including integer and floating-point literals, as
>   well as typical currency formatting, such as '$1,000.00'. Output is
>   generally in the latter form but depends on the locale.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Amounts(ID int, Value decimal(16,8), Value2 money);
>
> INSERT INTO Amounts VALUES
> (1, 100, 100), (2, 12.22636, 12.22636), (3, 0.1, 0.1);
>
> SELECT * FROM Amounts;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 3 rows affected
>
> id |        value |   value2
> -: | -----------: | -------:
>  1 | 100.00000000 | £100.00
>  2 |  12.22636000 |  £12.23
>  3 |   0.10000000 |   £0.10
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ddf82d8b838eb3be21f7817e2856c9d4)*

Answer (score 0):

No good answer...

`DECIMAL(16,8)` takes 8 bytes, as do `DOUBLE` and `BIGINT`.

8 integer digits (in decimal(16,8)) is sufficient for most monetary transactions, but not sufficient to talk about national GDP when expressed in USD, etc.  If that is needed, raise the `16` to make more room, at the expense of more bytes (*approx* 1 byte per 2 digits).

`DOUBLE` (no `(m,n)` *please*), can handle very large values, but suffers some roundoff issues.

`BIGINT` needs to be divided by the sub-units (10**8 for Bitcoin, 100 for USD/Euro, 10000 for a few other currencies.)